# corner detection in complex image

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, computer-vision, contour, corner-detection

[image]

I would like to find a fixed point in pictures like the above for latter comparison and i thought of taking the upper left corner of the board. I tried some things but the result is shown with the green dot. I would like to find a way to take that dot in the corner of the board, not above. I also want to make that point to be the same in a set of pictures of the same board but with some change in orientation maybe. I am using python 2.7

code i have tried so far:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 10, 200)
edged = cv2.dilate(edged, None, iterations=6)
edged = cv2.erode(edged, None, iterations=6)
(contourss, _) = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contourss = sorted(contourss, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[:10]
cv2.drawContours(image, contourss[0], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

rect1 = cv2.minAreaRect(contourss[0])
box1 = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect1)
box1 = np.int0(box1)
topleftPer=[]
for i in box1[1]:
    topleftPer.append(i)
pt = (topleftPer[0], topleftPer[1])
cv2.circle(image, pt, 5, (0, 255, 0), -1)
```

Comment: That corner is poorly defined as it is actually a curve. You should give better critera.

Answer (score 2):

Always amazing to see how people want to rely on edge detection. Edge detection is so unreliable !

This image is easy to binarize. Find the black pixel with the smallest value of x+y and place a small ROI around this pixel. Then use the leftmost and topmost coordinates.

[image]

Comment: could you provide some code cause i'm new to python?

Comment: @EugeneMoush: haha, that was made by hand.

Comment: @EugeneMoush: but it is no problem to achieve exactly that in programming.